# How shall I configure cpu frequency upon resuming from suspension of Ubuntu?

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate, cpufreq

**Problem:**

In Ubuntu 16.04, I run my shell script to scale down my cpu frequency  to be 1600000, and its governor to be  "userspace":

```
sudo /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000
```

which writes 1600000 and "userspace" to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` respectively.

However, after suspension and then waking up of my Ubuntu, the cpu frequency is  back up to 2667000, because `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` is rewritten by some unknown program to 2667000. I would like  cpu frequency to be kept at 1600000 after resuming from suspension.

**Tentative Solution:**

I tried one solution from https://superuser.com/a/733336/9265 (see below), and added a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` , whose content is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# upon resume from suspension, scale down the cpu freq
case "$1" in
   thaw|resume)
     /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000
     ;;
esac
```

and make it executable by `chmod a+x *` so that its permission is `-rwxrwxr-x`.
But it doesn't scale down the cpu frequency to 1600000 after resuming from suspension.

Is `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` actually run when resuming from suspension?
How can I verify that?

Is `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` overridden by some other configuration file?

There is no other script under `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` which deals with cpu frequency.

There is a system-default script `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq`, which deals with cpu frequency (see below for its content). Does someone know what the script does? Does it override or is it overridden by `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq`? (Note that if I rename `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` to  `/etc/pm/sleep.d/95cpufreq` or `/etc/pm/sleep.d/93cpufreq`, in order to change the order between it and `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq`, `both still don't scale down the cpu frequency to 1600000 upon resuming from suspension.)

In `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq`, it doesn't work either If I add `/home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000` after `thaw_cpufreq` in the case `resume|thaw)` .

Where shall I run `/home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000`, if not in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq`?

---

**Content of `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq`**

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                          
# Ensure cpu governor is set to something sane.                                                                                                                                    
# TODO: Which of the cpu governors is still insane?  File bugs against                                                                                                             
#       those that are.                                                                                                                                                            

. "${PM_FUNCTIONS}"

[ -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/ ] || exit $NA

hibernate_cpufreq()
{
  ( cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
  for x in cpu[0-9]*; do
    # if cpufreq is a symlink, it is handled by another cpu. Skip.                                                                                                                 
    [ -L "$x/cpufreq" ] && continue
    gov="$x/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
    # if we do not have a scaling_governor file, skip.                                                                                                                             
    [ -f "$gov" ] || continue
    # if our temporary governor is not available, skip.                                                                                                                            
    grep -q "$TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR" \
            "$x/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors" || continue
    savestate "${x}_governor" < "$gov"
    echo "$TEMPORARY_CPUFREQ_GOVERNOR" > "$gov"
  done )
}

thaw_cpufreq()
{
  ( cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
  for x in cpu[0-9]*/cpufreq/scaling_governor ; do
    [ -f "$x" ] || continue
    state_exists "${x%%/*}_governor" || continue
    restorestate "${x%%/*}_governor" > "$x"
  done )
}

case "$1" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    hibernate_cpufreq
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    thaw_cpufreq
    ;;
  *) exit $NA
    ;;
esac
```

---

**Copied from https://superuser.com/a/733336/9265**

> From manpage `pm-action(8)`:
>
> ```
> /etc/pm/sleep.d, /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d
>      Programs in these directories (called hooks) are combined
>      and executed in C sort order before suspend and hibernate
>      with as argument ´suspend´ or ´hibernate´. Afterwards they
>      are called in reverse order with argument ´resume´ and
>      ´thaw´ respectively. **If both directories contain a similar
>      named file, the one in /etc/pm/sleep.d will get preference.**
>      It is possible to disable a hook in the distribution
>      directory by putting a non-executable file in
>      /etc/pm/sleep.d, or by adding it to the HOOK_BLACKLIST
>      configuration variable.
> ```
>
> Thus you could simply put a shell-script like this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> case "$1" in
> suspend|hibernate)
>     actions to
>     take
>     on suspend
>     or hibernate
>     ;;
> resume|thaw)
>     other actions
>     to trigger
>     on resume
>     ;;
> esac
> ```
>
> into e.g. `99-myhooks.sh` and make it executable.
>
> BTW, you can kill stale SSH-connections by entering
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in the SSH
>   session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason (see [Why are there these differences between suspension by the DEs and by pm-utils? | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/435168/674)) which also leads to some new questions:

> I found some differences between running `pm-suspend` and   clicking
>   "Suspend" menu item in LXDE on Ubuntu 16.04
>
> 1. In both cases I can wake up Ubuntu by pushing the power button on my laptop, but in the way by "Suspend" menu item in LXDE, I have to
>      provide my password to unlock the screen, while in the way by
>      `pm-suspend` (and by`pm-hibernate` or `pm-suspend-hybrid`), I don't
>      need to.
> 2. According to this question: [How do I run commands on suspend/return from suspend? | Super User](https://superuser.com/a/733336/9265), scripts under `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` are supposed to be
>      executed upon suspension/hibernation and resuming/thawing.  But it is
>      true  only when I run `pm-suspend` (or`pm-hibernate` or
>      `pm-suspend-hybrid`), and false when I click "Suspend" menu item in
>      LXDE.
>
> I used to use Gnome, and I remember it was the same as in LXDE, except
>   Gnome might have hibernate option besides suspend.
>
> I wonder why there are the differences between suspension by the DEs
>   and by pm-utils?
>
> Can `pm-suspend` be used in a way so that resume requires password to
>   unlock the screen?
>
> Can "suspend" menu item in LXDE be used in a way so that the scripts
>   in  `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` are executed
>   upon suspension/hibernation and resuming/thawing?
>
> Thanks.